# Can't start minikube inside docker network

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, minikube

I'm trying to start minikube on ubuntu 18.04 inside nginx proxy manager docker network in order to setup some kubernetes services and manage the domain names and the proxy hosts in the nginx proxy manager platform.

so I have `nginxproxymanager_default` docker network and when I run `minikube start --network=nginxproxymanager_default` I get

> Exiting due to GUEST_PROVISION: Failed to start host: can't create with that IP, address already in use

what might I been doing wrong?

Comment: Hi dazzed! What k8s/minikube version are you using? Have you already solved the issue?

Answer (score 1):

A similar error was reported with [kubernetes/minikube issue 12894](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/12894)

> please check whether there are other services using that IP address, and try starting minikube again.

Considering [`minikube start` man page](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/start/)

> ### `--network string`
>
> network to run minikube with.
> Now it is used by docker/podman and KVM drivers.
>
> If left empty, minikube will create a new network.

Using an existing NGiNX network (as opposed to docker/podman) might not be supported.

I have seen [NGiNX set up as ingress](https://hackernoon.com/setting-up-nginx-ingress-on-kubernetes-2b733d8d2f45), not directly as "network".